# Login Internally to Dropbox Account from Android App

Tags: android, dropbox-api

In my project, I have an activity that downloads files from Dropbox and the basic method that uses the Dropbox account works. In the developer console, they provided an access token to make calls to the API without going through the authentication. However, there is no sample or hint to do so. I saw an example in [this link](https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2014/05/generate-an-access-token-for-your-own-account/), but it is for Ruby. Also, there is no `DropboxClient` in Android API. How can I make calls to the Dropbox API using the access token only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [generated OAuth 2 access token](https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2014/05/generate-an-access-token-for-your-own-account/) is generally only meant for testing/developing with your own account.

If you're using the [Dropbox Android Core SDK](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/android), you should follow the instructions in the [tutorial](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/android) for implementing the app authorization flow. This results in an access token for the user, (e.g., you, during testing, or each actual end-user when your app is released) that your app can store and re-use for future API calls for that user.

If this app is only for you though and you just want to supply your own OAuth 2 access token, you can use [AndroidAuthSession constructior](https://www.dropboxstatic.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.3-docs/com/dropbox/client2/android/AndroidAuthSession.html#AndroidAuthSession(com.dropbox.client2.session.AppKeyPair,%20java.lang.String)).